# open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can't be FP

Tags: algebraic-topology, fixed-point-theorems

The question we received is as follows:

**Show that an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ cannot have the fixed point property**

where A has the "fixed point property" if every continuous function from A to itself has a fixed point (for example $D^n$ has the fixed point property - Brouwer's Theorem)

I have seen that someone has already asked this for an open ball - where that is solved due to homeorphism to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Can this be generalized to every open set?

My attempt was to find a function that slightly moves each point - each points has a ball around it that is still in the set, but I'm having trouble showing this can be done continuously.

Comment: Let, for each $x \in U$, $r(x)$ be the smallest positive real number such that $B(x,r(x))$ isn’t contained in $U$. Clearly, $r(y) \geq r(x)-\|x-y\|$. It follows that $r$ is continuous. Let $u$ be a vector with norm $1/2$, take $f(x)=x+r(x)u$.